# How to use typed dependency to analyse sentence and generate response based on it?

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, stanford-nlp

I have to build a marketing auto-reply bot that can analyze the user input and based on it, it generates the reply.
For the purpose, I am using Standford Core NLP to get typed dependency of the sentence.
I have to get intent out of the sentence. I am not sure can we get intent by analyzing typed dependency of input if so then how?
And I can build training sets to train the machine.

Ex: Suppose I asked the customer: We Have xyz agency. Are you interested in it?
[Note: Most of the time question will be almost similar]

Reply from a customer: We don't have a scope for an agency as of now. (Typed Dependency for the sentence is
 [Dependency Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1g7zG.png))

So, the answers I want to know is as follows:
i.) Can we get intent out of sentence using typed dependency, if so how.
ii.) How will I build training sets.

Thanks in advance.